# Whats the `self` means in create(self, validated_data) method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Whats the `self` means in create(self, validated_data) method ?

I have a serializer named CloudServerPayOrderSerializer, and I want to override the create() method.

```
class CloudServerPayOrderSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TradeRecord
        exclude = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'traderecord_num', 
            'money',
            'balance',
            'desc', 
        )
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = getUserFormSerializer(self)
        ...
```

You see, I am override the create method, and I want to get user through `self`. so there is a util method `getUserFormSerializer`.

But I don't know the `self` here stands for what, whether it is stand for `CloudServerPayOrderSerializer`, if is not, I can not name the util method as `getUserFormSerializer`.

Comment: This is a basic Python question. If you don't recognize the use of self in a Python class, you should do an introductory language tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stands for a concrete object of this class you invoke this method upon. It can have any name (name it `this`, `object` or whatever you like) but it is always the very first argument to a non-static method, and yes, when you invoke the method on an actual object, that latter stands before the dot, not in parentheses.

So, in this case it is used as:

```
cspos = CloudServerPayOrderSerializer()
cspos.create(42)   # self is bound to cspos and validated_data to 42
```

Comment: In this scenario what it stands for?

Comment: Yes self can be any other name but don't be tempted to rename from the conventional 'self', because you risk causing endless confusion with other python programmers.